# Get value from mutually exclusive properties

Tags: typescript, union-types

Is there a cleaner way to get the value of either property (mutually exclusive) from a union? I can't add a discriminator/kind property because the object type comes from a package I don't maintain, and there's also no class type on either Object. I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require editing the library, casting types (which I currently have to do with `as`), or allowing `undefined` to be returned.

```
interface A {
  a: true
}
interface B {
  b: true
}

function getValue(obj: A | B): boolean | undefined {
  let value: boolean | undefined

  if (obj.hasOwnProperty("a")) {
    value = (obj as A).a
  } else if (obj.hasOwnProperty("b")) {
    value = (obj as B).b
  }

  return value
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define [custom type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) and use it to narrow the the type:

```
const isA = (obj: A | B): obj is A => obj.hasOwnProperty("a");

function getValue(obj: A | B): boolean | undefined {
    let value: boolean | undefined

    if (isA(obj)) {
        value = obj.a
    } else {
        value = obj.b
    }

    return value
}

// Or shorter
const getValue = (obj: A | B) => isA(obj) ? obj.a : obj.b;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQz-JwBcyYUArhLgL66iSyIoBCmuByARiWZTbrgQB7EAGcwyYKPQBeZAAohnAFYl0AH2TMAlCSXLJotMhkA+ZPoB0ACziiA8gHcQABShCADtDABPeQCI4f20AbgEcGHIQBDBgEWQAcwgwADU4ABtKRRU1ZE0dEk4hIXSIOBA85CiAEwgYUAhqtjwCUokANwzKQuLS8sqauobq8I5gGAUpVGzlbW1mjg5OzJQ5Kzh2AmpkCHTRFGwWxeRlyhMLFUtOTfxaHBvkKGTyKArTqhxqIA)

---

Another option is using [`in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator) (acts as a narrowing expression for types):

```
function getValue(obj: A | B): boolean | undefined {
    let value: boolean | undefined

    if ('a' in obj) {
        value = obj.a
    } else {
        value = obj.b
    }

    return value
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQz-JwBcyYUArhLgL66iSyIoBCmuByARiWZTbrhjkQCMMAD2IZAHMIYAGpwANpQAU4zgCsS6AD7JmAShKdx4pRDhT9wgCYQYoCLbZ4CFsMgBuyyibMWVsg2IPaOIM4CbvjAMMiqAORwCcigyBqahq4cHD4qKAC86VoAdHDsBNTIEEoAzijY0Tl5lMhFGSWcFfi0ON3IUHLkUFItVDjUQA)

Comment: Thanks, I realized I don't need the `value` variable in this case and I can simplify it to just `return 'a' in obj ? obj.a : obj.b` if I remove the return type.

Comment: Sure like suggested in first sample :) `const getValue = (obj: A | B) => isA(obj) ? obj.a : obj.b;`